# Group by in R to represent counts per county on a map?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, mapping, geography

[picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNHHj.png)

I have the data above in which I need to represent the companies in the last column for every US county on a map. The dea is to be able to hover over a county and have it say the company names. It came from an Excel pivot table which I collapsed down to a csv. My strategy is to add a column that summarizes the company counts per county so I can map that one variable. I'm not sure the best way  to do that, I'm assuming a column value that reads "Alabama Power Company (4) Wetterhorn Wireless L.L.C. (3)" or "Alabama Power Company Alabama Power Company Alabama Power Company Alabama Power Company Wetterhorn Wireless L.L.C. Wetterhorn Wireless L.L.C. Wetterhorn Wireless L.L.C." or something like that. Would I use a group by to do that? What's the best way to summarize this pivot table on a map?

Comment: I now see that I probably need to change the data from long to wide with counts, looking into how to do that

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: `group_by()` should work if you combine it with `summarise()` & `n()` you could also try and take a look at the `add_counts()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to represent it using aggregate:

summary =  aggregate(dt$company, list(dt$ccounty), paste, collapse=" ")

this yields all the names of the winners

Answer (score 0):

You can get the counts very easily if the data is loaded as a `data.table`. Just use `.N` along with 'by' to groupby by country and company

```
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(data)

dt[,count:=.N,by=.(country,company)]
```

Note:

- `data` should be your dataframe you load from your csv
- Replace `country` and `company` with names of your column of country and company from the data.table

Comment: Now that I have a counts column:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM5Gp.png

How do I add a new column that includes the other companies that are in that county? Something like "Alabama Power Company (4) Wetterhorn Wireless L.L.C. (3)"

Comment: Do you just need the count of all the companies which are in each county?
`dt[,count:=.N,by=.(county)]` should work

Comment: No that just returns the total count (7) not how many of each (4 Alabama and 3 Wetterhorn)

Comment: I am sorry, your question is not very clear. Please post a sample output.